# Secret Windows keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, function-keys

So, my keyboard has a function key that opens Settings in Windows 10. With AutoHotKey, I discovered that the keyboard shortcut used is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F21</kbd>. Here's the key history:

```
VK  SC Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5B  15B     d   40.38   LWin            
84  06C     d   0.02    F21             
84  06C     u   0.00    F21             
5B  15B     u   0.01    LWin
```

I searched, but there's no reference to this shortcut in the [official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts). Also, pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> does nothing and AutoHotKey does not log it as <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F21</kbd>.

This makes me wonder if is there any other "secret" keyboard shortcuts in Windows that keyboard manufacturers know of and where could those be found.

Comment: So you question is.. "Is there any other secret windows shortcut around?" or "Is this a valid windows shortcut key?"  ?

Comment: "Is there any other secret windows shortcut around?". I know it is valid because it works.

Comment: IMHO, better put that as your question title.. ( :